# Delete document from search query

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

i use this request for get all(200) documents duplicated in my index, and i want delete all documents in this result. I tried tu use _delete_by_query but after many try and search on internet i failed ...

My query is :

```
GET /index-ip/_query
{
  "aggs": {
      "dup": {
         "terms": {
            "size" : 200,
            "field": "ip_commune.keyword",
            "min_doc_count": 2
     }
    }
  }
}
```

returned result :

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 754,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "V64TV2kB0AORAV2GIdMZ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "98.183.164.36",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-ipam"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.874Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "Dq4TV2kB0AORAV2GIdUe",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "136.168.48.254",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.979Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "264TV2kB0AORAV2GIdUf",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "137.83.124.226",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.889Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "F64TV2kB0AORAV2GIdUe",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "136.168.50.1",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.980Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "Iq4TV2kB0AORAV2GIdUe",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "136.168.86.91",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:25.003Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "Za4TV2kB0AORAV2GIdYh",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "137.69.223.4",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.888Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "Z64TV2kB0AORAV2GIdYh",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "137.78.101.254",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.888Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "aa4TV2kB0AORAV2GIdYh",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "137.83.29.198",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.890Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "d64TV2kB0AORAV2GIdYh",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "98.183.164.55",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.916Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index-ip",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "-a4TV2kB0AORAV2GIdUf",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "ip_commune" : "98.183.164.117",
          "@version" : "1",
          "tags" : [
            "ip-glpi"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-03-07T07:34:24.899Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "dup" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.124",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.142",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.166",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.172",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.232",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.25",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.27",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.28",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.29",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.35",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.36",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.37",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.38",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.39",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.164.58",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.21",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.22",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.23",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.24",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.25",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.27",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "98.183.27.28",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to keep one of the duplicate records =) I need to delete both of them.
My goal is to compare two ITSM(GLPI) and IPAM IP lists to extract all IP addresses not in GLPI
Any idea ? :confused:  and sorry for my bad english ^^

Comment: It depends on which version of ES you're using. Which one is it?

Comment: Did you see this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html, Just to remember, you may want to keep one of the duplicate records :) if you write your query to find mic_doc_count=2 delete all of them.

Comment: @Val I use version 6.6.1 of elastic stack

Comment: @ibrahimozgon nop i don't want to keep one of the duplicate records =) I need to delete both of them. And thank for the doc i have already read it but i don't know what is the right syntax for using my search result to delete them :/

Comment: Okay guy's if you don't have a solution, just python :D

Comment: How are you adding the documents to ES? If you set the document `_id` to be the IP address, and upserted them (with a ITSM or IPAM field depending on the source) you could then run a query to identify documents that have both fields set and delete those